# Modifying a dictionary in a python loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to count the number of letters in some text by adding each incidence to a dictionary then adding to it if needed. However, the dictionary appears blank at the end. What am I doing wrong?

```
text = "test 1234!"
dic = {}
for char in text:
    for key, value in dic:
        if key == char:
            value = value + 1
        else:
            dic[char] = 1
print(dic)
```

Thanks

Comment: It will be because you don't have any key value pairs in your dictionary.

Comment: The inner loop iterates over an empty dictionary.

Comment: use ```for key, value in dic.items()```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to iterate over the dict, you can just check if the key `char` already exists:

```
dic = {}
for char in text:
    if char in dic:
        dic[char] += 1
    else:
        dic[char] = 1
print(dic)
# Out: {'t': 2, 'e': 1, 's': 1, ' ': 1, '1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 1, '4': 1, '!': 1}
```

Besides writing this yourself, you can also use implemented modules to do things like this. One option would be `Counter` from the `collections` module, which will also return a `dict`:

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(text)
print(counts)
# Out: Counter({'t': 2,
#               'e': 1,
#               's': 1,
#               ' ': 1,
#               '1': 1,
#               '2': 1,
#               '3': 1,
#               '4': 1,
#               '!': 1})
```

Comment: You are welcome and thanks for accepting the answer! In general I'd recommend using `Counter`, since the implementation of the `collections` module is optimized for performance.

Answer (score 1):

here you go:

```
text = 'test 12234!'
dic = {}
for char in text:
    if char in dic.keys():
        dic[char] += 1
    else:
        dic[char] = 1
print(dic)
```

Output:

```
{'t': 2, 'e': 1, 's': 1, ' ': 1, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 1, '4': 1, '!': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `defaultdict` to avoid the if-else or any iteration over the dictionary altogether.

```
from collections import defaultdict

text = "test 1234!"
dic = defaultdict(int)

for char in text:
    dic[char] += 1

print(dic)
```

A `defaultdict` assigns an intial default value in-case the key does not exist in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The dic you declared is blank so looping in it will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

text = "test 1234!"
dct = Counter(text)


print(dct)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While your code may provide the answer to the question, please add context/explanation to it so others will have some idea what it does and why it is there.